# How to deal with illegal characters in javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript function that I am calling in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    opener.postConditionPostCure(
        "<?php echo get_field('cure_description'); ?>"
    );
</script>
```

The issue is that I do not know what will be echoed by the php. I just ran into an issue where the javascript is failing because the php is echoing an illegal token, in this case the "(". How can this issue be dealt with. Thanks.

Comment: As long as the argument is a string, that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do, but think that the php is a language for server-side and javascript is for client-side.
If you want to try something like this:
var a = "<?php echo get_field('cure_description'); ?>";
console.log(a);

Comment: try json_encode (without your own ")

Answer (score 0):

A desirable thing to do would be to ensure that php returns normalized data, `JSON` string perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

I hate having php intermingled with my js makes it hard to read the js
I prefer to declare it as variables at the top of my js code if possible (and it usually is)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var description = <?php echo json_encode(get_field('cure_description')); ?>;

    opener.postConditionPostCure(description);
</script>
```