# passing special characters to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code: `opener.postConditionPostCure("<?php echo the_field('cure_description'); ?>")`

In some cases the_field() returns ' " ) characters. I believe these characters are throwing errors. I have tried using the js fn escape() function as well as the php fn rawurlencode() as:

```
opener.postConditionPostCure(escape("<?php echo the_field('cure_description'); ?>"))
opener.postConditionPostCure("<?php echo rawurlencode(the_field('cure_description')); ?>")
```

to no avail.

I would like the entire string returned by the_field() to be passed to the postConditionPostCure function.

All advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Encode it as JSON. [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Comment: "not working" is the most useless feedback.

Comment: Why are you [asking the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793124/how-to-deal-with-illegal-characters-in-javascript-function-parameters) again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is horrible.**

Never ever, ever, ever integrate dynamic output directly into javascript like that.

[Read the plethora of reasons why this is a terrible practice here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript).

---

But since you're just going to do it anyway, at least encode the JavaScript value properly first.

```
var json = '<?php echo json_encode(the_field("cure_description"), JSON_HEX_APOS) ?>';

var cureDescription = JSON.parse(json);

opener.postConditionPostCure(cureDescription);
```

I'm calling `json_encode` with the `JSON_HEX_APOS` flag because I'm wrapping the JSON in `'` (single quotes) in the JavaScript.

---

You have two other more ideal options at your disposal though

1. use ajax to get the value you need
2. render a `<input type="hidden">` and fetch the value using JavaScript.

Both solutions avoid embedding PHP directly in your JS.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. It is really helpful. Ill work on it now and see what I come up with

Comment: @bob no problem. If you have other questions, I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP function `addslashes()` which will escape those characters that are causing chaos in js.

```
opener.postConditionPostCure("<?php echo addslashes(the_field('cure_description')); ?>")
```

Comment: It has to work, that's what that function does. Can you paste what your script renders?

Comment: opener.postConditionPostCure("text:<br />

Comment: Where is the `")`? That's part of the JS, it should already be there.

Comment: I think it is erroring out by the >, sorry, I should have included that symbol as well.